# Escaping ':' and '?' in parameterized SQL queries in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to know how to escape `?` and `:` in SQL queries in general.

These are just arbitrary examples:

```
Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title, author, content FROM post where author = ? AND RIGHT(content, 1) = '?'", @author]
```

(finding posts ends with `?`)

```
Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title, author, content FROM post where author = :author AND title LIKE 'Foo:bar%'", {author:@author}]
```

(finding posts starts with `foo:bar`)

I'm not asking how to escaping to prevent injection. I am asking when I am using parametrized queries, rails will see `?` and `:some_var` as parameters. But what if I want to use `?` and `:stuff` as part of the queries? How do I escape them so Rails will treat them as strings instead of trying to find a matching parameter?

I know a solution will be writing these two queries like:

```
Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title, author, content FROM post where author = ? AND RIGHT(content, 1) = ?", @author, '?']

Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title, author, content FROM post where author = :author AND title LIKE CONCAT(:name, '%')", {author:@author, name:'foo:bar'}]
```

But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I don't get your question ....... :)

Comment: The problem is rails will see the ? and :bar as parameters instead of strings. But I want rails to see them as strings.

Comment: You can use the build-in functions like Post.where("author = \? and title like '%?%'", @title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `quote` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote

I know you said "in general", but the above two queries can be written using ActiveRecord so you can avoid having to quote things yourself.

Comment: Can you explain more please? I don't see how would I make use of quote in these two examples. The purpose is not to prevent SQL injection. The problem is rails will see the ? and :bar as parameters instead of strings.